# Jquery draggable droppable can not show multi divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I followed the jquery ui draggable and droppable to try to show 3 divs in a specific area.
Here is the code:
--CSS:

```
#content-1 { width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red; display: none; }
        #content-2 { width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red; display: none; }
        #content-3 { width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red; display: none; }
```

--js:

```
$(function() {
            $("#li-1").draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone"
            });
            $(".ui-widget-content").droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#content-1").show();
                }
            });
            $("#li-2").draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone"
            });
            $(".ui-widget-content").droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#content-2").show();
                }
            });
            $("#li-3").draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone"
            });
            $(".ui-widget-content").droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#content-3").show();
                }
            });
        });
```

--HTML:

```
<div id="products">
        <div id="catalog">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li id="li-1">dashboard-1</li>
                    <li id="li-2">dashboard2</li>
                    <li id="li-3">dashboard3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cart">
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
            <div id="content-1"></div>
            <div id="content-2"></div>
            <div id="content-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The result is it just can show only one div. What is the bug in this code?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the nuisance of putting your code into http://jsbin.com to see what's happening out there. Next time please care to do it yourself.

Your problem is that you're defining the same function `.droppable` to the same element `.ui-widget-content`. So naturally you're rewriting the definition of the same function three times and only the last definition is working.

Here's how you want it to be done:

```
$(function() {
        $("#li-1").draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
        });
        $("#li-2").draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
        });
        $("#li-3").draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
        });
        $(".ui-widget-content").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {

              // Retrieving the id of the element being dragged
              var element = ui.draggable.attr('id');

              if (element == "li-1") {
                $("#content-1").show();
              } else if (element == "li-2") {
                $("#content-2").show();
              } else if (element == "li-3") {
                $("#content-3").show();
              }
            }
        });
    });
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ozixur/3/edit

Comment: I would definitely tweak the function to avoid all the hard-coded stuff. Otherwise, every time you add an li to the html, the js code must change as well....

Comment: @netrunner, sure man, it's just an example to explain what's going on there.